# How to use on_message with database in discord.py?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

Hi my bot is in multiple guilds and I want it to give a specific role when user mentions any 1 user in a specific channel, I chose sqlite3 for the job and wrote this,

Structure:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main(
            guild_id TEXT,
            channel_id TEXT,
            role_id TEXT
        )
    ''')
```

Cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import datetime
import sqlite3

class TestCog(commands.Cog, name='test') :

    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot



    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.guild:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM main WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result:
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(result[2])
                role = message.guild.get_role(result[1])
                if role:
                    if message.channel == channel:
                        if len(message.mentions) >= 1:
                            await message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
                            user = message.author
                            await user.add_roles(role)


    @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def test(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send('Test command running...')

    @test.command()
    async def channel(self, ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
        db= sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}')
        result =  cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, channel_id) VALUES(?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id,channel.id)
            await ctx.send(f'Test channel has been set to {channel.mention}')
        elif result is not None:
            sql = ("UPDATE main SET channel_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
            val = (channel.id, ctx.guild.id)
            await ctx.send(f'Test channel has been updated to {channel.mention}')
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()

    @test.command()
    async def role(self, ctx,role: discord.Role):
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT role_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
        result =  cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO main (guild_id, role_id) VALUES(?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id, role.id)
            await ctx.send(f" Role set to `{role}`")
        elif result is not None:
            sql = ("UPDATE main SET role_id = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
            val = (role.id, ctx.guild.id)
            await ctx.send(f"Default role have been updated to  `{role}`")
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()

    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        raise error


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
    print("Test cog is loaded!")
```

Table ss to show structure:
[image]
I have checked the role command channel command are working and storing data properly in db, The problem is with `on_message`. It doesn't throw error but doesn't work if a user mentions someone. I can't really figure that out. Can you see anything wrong with on_message part or in any part of the code?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Nurqm It doesn't throw any error. Also doesn't give reaction or add role to the user when they mentions anyone in that channel

Comment: Can you try to remove these `channel = self.bot.get_channel(result[2])
role = message.guild.get_role(result[1])` and replace  `channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, id=result[2])
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=result[1)`

Comment: @Nurqm I have already tried that , doesn't work :(

Comment: Why did you do `if result`, `if message.guild`?

Comment: @Nurqm honestly, I don't understand database , I just took some video tutorial references and coded this.  So I don't really know what this `if`  do there but I certainly tried the same code without these if statements, still that was of no use

Comment: Is it saving data succesfully? And can you  add screenshot of your database tabel and a simple data?

Comment: @Nurqm yup for sure! Edited the image into question